# Harmonic analysis: Bm7b5 E7 Fmaj7

Tags: theory, scales, chord-theory, chord-progressions

Bm7b5, E7, Fmaj7 are of course the 2nd, 5th and 6th degree of A harmonic minor, but if I'm in Fmaj what are they?

Comment: A harmonic minor isn't a key - it's a scale.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Honestly, I'd rather ditch the notion that you're in F major for the entire chord progression. Tonicize/modulate to A minor if necessary.

Comment: What have you established as the key around that point in the piece? There may be no need (apart from academic) to be in F.

Comment: How do you propose that you're in `F` major? Where is the `B` flat coming from? Is your idea that the last chord - or one of the chords - of the progression should be considered the tonic chord? Why arbitrarily choose a key that doesn't sound right when you already imply the tonic is `A` minor?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, I thought the first 3 questions were good, but when I saw the 4th they seemed disingenuous. How can you call the choice of F∆ arbitrary if you don't know the answer to your first 3 questions?

Comment: @Clabis it seems your question is unclear. Is Bø E7 Fmaj7 a progression, or just three chords appearing at various times? Could you edit your question to include the progression, perhaps with what is preceding it, for the context?

Comment: @user1079505, those are good questions (which could produce deeper answers), but I do think this question is perfectly answerable as written. Even if the intended progression *were* | Bø7 E7 | FMaj |, there is no rule prohibiting this progression from appearing in a song whose key is F. I think the answer to this question is simple: Bø7 and E7 are the ♯IVø and VII7 in the key of F. Maybe we can't expand very much (from a Western analysis standpoint), but I think that doesn't change the fact that Bø7 and E7 are the ♯IVø and VII7 in the key of F.

Comment: @jdjazz, I'm not getting into some Lydian Chromatic nonsense. It isn't in F major, because there isn't a B flat anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, please try to refrain from using a rude tone. Your last comment leads to a few thoughts: (1) Why did you ask questions if your mind is already made up? (2) It's puzzling that you've made up your mind when you seem to be aware of the fact that a lot of information is yet to be ascertained. (3) Is measure 9 of Night and Day by Cole Porter "lydian chromatic nonsense"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the key of FMaj, the chords Bø7 and E7 are the ♯ivø and VII7, respectively. FMaj, of course, would be the I.

In jazz, the ♯ivø and VII7 chords commonly appear in progressions like this:

```
| Bø7 E7alt | Amin7 D7alt | Gmin7 C7 | FMaj7   |
```

which are characterized by a sequence of ii-V's that take us around the circle of 5ths.

The ♯IVø also frequently appears in progressions like this (as we see in Night and Day by Cole Porter):

```
| Bø7       | B♭min7      | Amin7    | A♭dim   |
| Gmin7     | C7          | FMaj7    |         |
```

Note: for convenience I've written Bmin7♭5 as Bø7, but they mean the same thing. I've tried to write an answer that:

- accepts the stated assumption that the key is FMaj,
- identifies the function of the given chords (as requested), and
- provides examples of how those chords typically appear.

Comment: This answer takes the OP's _clear_ progression, moves the half diminished seventh chord into _different harmonic contexts_ of sequential and parallel harmony, and then tries to label `Bø7` as `F:♯IVø` _before_ the `F: ii V I` establishes `F` as tonic. Before those endings in `F` _there is no reason_ to identify `Bø7` as `F:♯IVø`. In the first case `Bø7` _actually sounds_ like `Am:iiø7`, in the second case I see no point in RNA for the parallel motion. Just label the ending `ii V I`. Not everything needs RNA. And, again, neither has anything to do with the OP's progression.

Comment: The think that especially bothers me about this misuse of RNA is there can be a legitimate reason to use an altered `#IV` label: an augmented sixth chord. German augmented sixth chords normally get a label like `Ger+6`, but you could also write it in RNA as `#IV+6/5`, which makes sense, because the chord _actually has subdominant function_.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, the OP marked this as the official answer; in my mind that suggests you've misread the question. I don't think the chords were intended as a progression. The sorts of reasons you've provided about why Bø7 is not in FMaj reveal wide gaps in understanding of jazz harmony, IMHO. I've corrected a typo; I meant to write ♯ivø.

Answer (score 6):

Something unnecessarily and un-helpfully complicated!

Analyse it in relation to the tonal centres it DOES visit.

Bm7♭5, E7 are standard approach chords to A minor.  But instead of the expected resolution to that chord, we have an Interrupted Cadence (I think Americans call it a 'Deceptive Cadence') to F.   What happens next?  Maybe F major persists as the new tonal centre, so it makes sense to start analysing in F major from that point on.  Maybe it's just an interrupted cadence in A minor, so it makes sense to keep analysing with that key centre.

[image]

Comment: Who downvoted this? Why? It so concisely explains the whole story including a _sensible_ way that `F` major might be tonicized. With notation even! So we don't need to guess about voicings, etc.

Comment: Good point about 'from this point on'. Which still leaves the original 3 chords around Am. +1.

Comment: The only thing missing is how to analyze `C7 F` in `D` minor. Sorry, snarky, but not really. If you get my joke, then you understand the meaning of the first sentence in this answer: "Something unnecessarily and un-helpfully complicated!"

Comment: I think there's a good chance this answer has misinterpreted the question. The OP doesn't mention a chord progression | Bø E7 | F∆ |. The chords are simply in a list. The chord progression could be something like: | Bø E7 | Am D7 | Gm C7 | F∆ | which is not uncommon in jazz. Laurence, I think your answer doesn't apply to that scenario. I think it's premature to say the Q is premised on unnecessary and unhelpful complications when there are many unanswered questions (what's the genre, what's the full chord progression, is the stipulation of F∆ purely hypothetical or inferred from other info?)

Comment: @LaurencePayne, I'm also wondering now if you agree that it's *impossible* for the key center to be FMaj during the progression Bø-E7-FMaj. I wouldn't normally expect that type of strictness from you, which is why I think I'm misunderstanding your answer. The example you shared has very insightful analysis; I love the progression you wrote out. But your first two sentences give me the impression that a rule exists prohibiting the analysis of Bø-E7-FMaj using a tonal center of FMaj.

Comment: @ jdjazz You don’t choose tonal centres, they arise. Sometimes clearly and inarguably, sometimes more ambiguously.  Sure, you can give any chord a functional label relating to any arbitrary  tonic.   And yes, if the quoted chords were not in sequence, my answer would probably have been different.